# Are Java streams meant only to be used for arrays? How about single elements?

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-stream

I have been looking at Java streams and functional programming.
Figured a way to rewrite a small "user login" code.

Here is my login methods;
*If the user from query is null, null pointer exception is handled on a filter.*

```java
    public ResponseEntity login(User request) {
        User dbUser = userRepo.findByEmail(request.getEmail());
        if (!aes.matches(request.getPassword(), dbUser.getPassword()))
            return ResponseEntity.status(403).build();

        return logUserIn(dbUser);
    }

    private ResponseEntity logUserIn(User dbUser) {
        dbUser.setPassword(null);
        jwtHandler.setJwtCookie(dbUser);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(dbUser);
    }
```

And via using streams;

```java
    public ResponseEntity login(User request) {
        return Stream.of(userRepo.findByEmail(request.getEmail()))
                .filter(dbUser -> aes.matches(request.getPassword(), dbUser.getPassword()))
                .map(this::logUserIn)
                .findFirst()
                .orElse(ResponseEntity.status(403).build());
    }

    private ResponseEntity logUserIn(User dbUser) {
        dbUser.setPassword(null);
        jwtHandler.setJwtCookie(dbUser);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(dbUser);
    }
```

I dont know if streams are meant to be used this way. Are they?
If i use similar kind of logic on more important parts of the project will I get in trouble later?

Comment: `filter` gives you all matching records. You don't need/want this, do you? Also, `map`ping users to `ResponseEntity`ies is not very idiomatic.

Comment: Optional has a lot of methods analogous to stream methods, and may be a more obvious tool for dealing with a single object.

Comment: findByEmail method returns only 1 user or null.

Comment: I'll check out Optional, thanks.

Comment: Neither Stream nor Optional should be used as a substitute for `if` and `else`.

Comment: That's what I want to know more about. Anything I can read on that?

Comment: Generally, there is nothing wrong with creating a single element stream. The documentation of `Stream.of(…)` does not name any restriction regarding the number of elements, in fact, there is [an overload for single arguments](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#of-T-) to handle this use case more efficiently. But in your specific case you replaced a simple four line code with a syntactically more complex five line code with no benefit. And the changed code does `.orElse(ResponseEntity.status(403).build());` evaluating the expression even when not needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might feel better about the `if-else` if you use it in a more functional style rather than short-circuiting:

```
if (!aes.matches(request.getPassword(), dbUser.getPassword())) {
    return ResponseEntity.status(403).build();
}
else {
    return logUserIn(dbUser);
}
```

Doing equivalent in one statement with Stream/Optional is harder to read and less performant.

You might consider the possibility of making `findByEmail` return `Optional<User>`, which is more idiomatic for any "find" method. Then you could combine the two approaches like

```
return userRepo.findByEmail(request.getEmail()).map(dbUser -> {
    if (!aes.matches(request.getPassword(), dbUser.getPassword())) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(403).build();
    }
    else {
        return logUserIn(dbUser);
    }
})... // .orElse(null) / .orElseThrow(...)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Returning Optional from repository and filtering/mapping on that makes more sense than using streams.

Comment: Good idea to use `Optional` instead of returning `null`

Answer (score 1):

You'll get into trouble, mostly. The 'root' problem is that both ways of writing it are defensible as the 'best choice', and the java community, by and large, strongly prefers the second form. For the same reason it is a bad idea to `name_variables_like_this` (the community decided that the convention is to `nameThemLikeThis`). Breaking the mold will mean your code is harder to read by others and code written by others is harder to read for you. Also, you'll probably get friction when you try to interact with other code.

For example, right now (and for the foreseeable future), 'lambdas' (those things with the `::` and the `->`) are NOT exception transparent, NOT control flow transparent, and NOT mutable local variable transparent.

There are only 3 feasible options here:

1. Somehow write all code such that these 3 transparencies are *never* relevant regardless of what you're writing. That sounds impossible to me. Even if you somehow you manage, there are other libraries out there. Starting with `java.*`, which isn't designed for that kind of code style.
2. Mix code styles, going with lambda style when you don't immediately foresee the transparencies being relevant, otherwise going with the more imperative style if it is or you think it might be. This sounds silly to me; why mix 2 styles when a single style would have covered all the use cases?
3. Stick with lambda style, bending over backwards to account for the lack of these 3 transparencies where it bothers you, 'downgrading' variables to `AtomicX` variants, using such constructs to transmit exceptions and boolean flags to carry break and continue control flow outside, etectera. This is just writing ugly code just because you are particularly eneamoured of your fancy new shiny hammer and are just insisting on treating all problems as a nail, no?

That's.. trying to guess at what's going to happen when you interact with other code and other programmers. This snippet, in a vacuum, with just you? Eh, both work fine. Whatever you prefer, if community, friction with other code, and having a consistent style doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

I have used Java 8 streams in live code and the biggest drawback for me is the stacktrace you get when an exception goes unhandled in the pipeline.

Sure they are nice to write and give you a sense of writing code in a functional style, but the truth is that streams are just a facade because underneath the fancy API, you are dealing with a monstrous abstraction layer over plain, ugly Java iterators, and this becomes painfully obvious when something goes awry such as an exception not being handled.

So the answer to your question is **yes you might get in trouble**, but it depends on how good you are at reading stacktraces, where 70% of the trace has nothing to do with code you've written but rather with the magic stuff used to turn iterators into streams.

As much as possible, prefer using `if-else`, `for-loops`, etc, unless you are confident that streams will be more efficient or easier to read. On that note, *readability* is quite important and part of the reason the `Stream` api exists is to improve readability, but moderation and good judgement are virtues worth exercising when making use of the full potential of the Streams API.

Comment: Thank you. I have been studying these subjects only for a couple of days. Your input is much appreciated.